# Not able to populate Kendo Tree View properly based on combo box selection in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I want to populate the Kendo treeview with different values based on a Kendo combo box selection, I created a jsfiddle to illustrate my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/KendoDev/Z4rwQ/3/

In this example, When Combo box value is **ClassA**, then If I select any node then selected node details are displayed in the message box properly, when I select **ClassB** then TreeView is not populated at all, to achieve this I need to empty the DOM before re populating treeview.

```
 `$( "#treeview" ).empty();` .
```

If I do this, then when changing the combo box selection, tree view is re populated properly.

But If I select any nodes for **ClassB** selection then treeview is becoming in operable, Even if I go back to ClassA selection, that option is also not working, any help on what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not just empty the widgets parent div and recreate the widget.  You first have to [destroy it](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/widget#methods-destroy).

```
var tV = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
if (tV){
    tV.destroy();
}
$( "#treeview" ).empty();
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4rwQ/4/).

Comment: I didn't think that destroy is implemented for Treeview control, thank you very much!!